# A combinatorial inequality $\binom {2n}{k} + \binom {2n}{n-k} \ < \ \binom{2n}{n} + \binom{2n}{0} \ \ \text{for} \ \ k<n \ \ $

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

I am struggling some math problems.

Fighting some problems, I find out a rule.

$$$$

Could you please see the table below?

[image]

HERE is my question!

I (may) found out the inequality

$$$$

$$\binom {2n}{k} + \binom {2n}{n-k}  \ < \ \binom{2n}{n} + \binom{2n}{0} \  \ \text{for} \ \ k<n  \ \ \cdots(1)$$

or

$$\binom {2n}{k} + \binom {2n}{n-k}  \ < \ \binom{2n}{l} + \binom{2n}{n-l} \  \ \text{for} \ \ k<l \le n  \ \ \cdots(2)$$

$$\text{Actually (2) implies (1)}$$
$$$$

1. Is these inequality exist already?
2. Is these inequality true, INTUITIVELY?
3. Is these inequality TRUE?
4. If these are right, then how can I proof?

$$$$
(I wanna believe these are true, and then these will proof simply...)

Thank you for your attention to this matter.

Comment: It fails for $k=0$.

Comment: The inequality $(1)$ does not hold for $(n,k)=(2,1),(3,1),(3,2)$.